# file() [function.file]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration error

Tags: php

my code is

```
<?php
if ($_POST['hiddensms']) {
    ini_set("allow_url_fopen", "ON");
    ini_set("allow_url_include", "ON");
    $smsno = explode(',', $_POST['hiddensms']);
    foreach ($smsno as $mono) {
        $baseurl         = "http://api.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com";
        $sql_q           = "select firstname,lastname from tbl_newsletter where phone='" . $mono . "'";
        $resultcount     = mysql_query($sql_q);
        $row_total_count = mysql_fetch_array($resultcount);
        $first_name      = $row_total_count['firstname'];
        $last_name       = $row_total_count['lastname'];
        if ($_POST['sel_name_sms'] == 'FirstName') {
            $setname = $first_name;
        } else {
            $setname = $last_name;
        }
        $smsBodyText = $_POST['sal_sms'] . ' ' . $setname . '\n';
        $text        = urlencode($smsBodyText . $_POST['msg_body']);
        $to          = $mono;
        $url         = "$baseurl/http/auth?user=$user&password=$password&api_id=$api_id";
        // do auth call
        $ret         = file($url);
        // explode our response. return string is on first line of the data returned
        $sess        = explode(":", $ret[0]);
        if ($sess[0] == "OK") {
            $sess_id = trim($sess[1]); // remove any whitespace
            $url     = "$baseurl/http/sendmsg?user=xx&password=xxxxx&api_id=3370743&to=$to&text=$text";
            //ht$ret = file($url);
            $send    = explode(":", $ret[0]);
            if ($send[0] == "ID") {
                echo "success\nmessage ID: " . $send[1];
            } else {
                echo "send message failed";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Authentication failure: " . $ret[0];
        }
    }
}
?>
```

i am trying to send sms by api, but is giving me this error

Warning: file() [function.file]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in /xxxxxxxsubscriber-list.php on line 622
    Warning: file(http://api.xxxxx.com/http/auth?user=xx&xx&api_id=xx) [function.file]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /xxxxxx/subscriber-list.php on line 622
    Authentication failure:

i set .htaccess like

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_admin_value allow_url_fopen On
php_admin_value allow_url_include On
</IfModule>
```

but its not working. i dont know what to do, if any idea, please help me

i have searched out on some web they  suggest to in  `php.ini`

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On
```

but i can't access `php.ini` , so any other way to soved this ?

Comment: maybe try `php_admin_flag` instead of `php_admin_value`  http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: i use `php_admin_flag` but till give error

Comment: May be it's listed in the disable_functions at php.ini

Comment: If curl is installed, you can use that without allow_url_fopen.  On an unrelated note there's actually no good reason to enable `allow_url_include` in this example. `allow_url_include` is pretty much always a bad idea.

Comment: Oh, on closer examination of the docs: `php_admin_*` cannot be used in htaccess.  That's why your changes to htaccess did nothing.  Try `php_flag allow_url_fopen on`

Comment: i change my `.htaccess` like `<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag allow_url_fopen On
php_flag allow_url_include On
</IfModule>` but till gives error

Comment: You really should sanitize $mono with `filter_var()` or `preg_replace()` to give you only digits; you can't be sure it contains only phone numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This error is telling you that allow_url_fopen is turned off on your server. It IS possible to config a server to ignore user defined php.ini files they place in their web root. Since they went through this trouble, they probably blocked you from alternative hacks (such as in your htaccess file) too.

allow_url_fopen is disabled by your host for SECURITY reasons! It should be, and should remain, disabled. So stop trying to turn it on. They don't want people running who knows what, getting hacked, and putting the other people on the server at risk.

The only way to get around this is to get a new host, or get a VPS or dedicated server where you have root access.

The alternative to allow_url_fopen would be cURL. You can do the same thing with curl.

cURL Example: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php